# Is there a R ggplot function to fill a bar chart with a different variable/dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I have created the following bar chart using:

```
structure(list(variable = structure(1:3, .Label = c("count_B", 
"count_M", "count_T"), class = "factor"), value = c(10.7894136128261, 
5.99274994891311, 4.10457180326646)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

`ggplot(meltedMUSICC, aes(x = variable, y = value, width = 0.95)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + coord_flip()`

[image]

I have another data set that specifies the fill by way of a percentage or relative abundance (out of 1) of each of the variables, it looks like this:

```
structure(list(phylum = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Acidobacteria", 
"Actinobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Amoebozoa"), class = "factor"), 
    count_T = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2), count_M = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.7), count_B = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Is there a function I could use to fill the bar chart so it becomes a stacked bar chart with the second data set, colour it and get a legend?

Comment: You have four values for `count_T` in the 2nd data set. How do you want to handle them and decide a color?

Comment: It would be nice to have a reproducible example. You can post your data using the `dput()` function

Comment: The values of the 'count_*'s are to specify 20% of 'count_T' bar should be for example coloured red and labelled Acidobacteria and so on. I posted all my code/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in how you aggregate the data. I assume that the count in your first dataframe is the sum of all relative counts in your second data frame.

**EDIT**

Thanks for posting the data

```r
    library(ggplot2)
    library(tidyverse)

    df <- structure(list(variable = structure(1:3, .Label = c("count_B", 
                                                              "count_M", "count_T"), class = "factor"), value = c(10.7894136128261, 
                                                                                                                  5.99274994891311, 4.10457180326646)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

    df2 <- structure(list(phylum = structure(1:4, .Label = c("Acidobacteria", 
                                                      "Actinobacteria", "Alphaproteobacteria", "Amoebozoa"), class = "factor"), 
                   count_T = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.2), count_M = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
                                                                0.7), count_B = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                            -4L))

    df3 <- df2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = -phylum) %>% 
      left_join(df, by = c("name" = "variable")) %>% 
      mutate(new_count = value.x*value.y)
    #> Warning: Column `name`/`variable` joining character vector and factor,
    #> coercing into character vector

    ggplot(df3, aes(x = name, y = new_count)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = phylum))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for filling the gaps and assuming. This is what I wanted to achieve, thank you for your help.